# java.util.pref.WindowsPreferences Class is not available in JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I just noticed in [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/prefs/AbstractPreferences.html) , WindowsPreferences class is **missing**.
I checked online versions of **Java Docs for Java5,6,7 and Java 8**.

[image]

But, this class is **exists in JDK 7 (jdk1.7.0_79)**.

I can see this class as shown. Some other class such as java.util.pref.XmlSupport also missing in JavaDoc.

[image]

I **was** believing that JavaDoc documents **every available class** in Java, Is this belief wrong/not the reality?

Comment: The `class` is not `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation around Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html) generation -

> The Javadoc tool parses the declarations and documentation comments in
>   a set of Java source files and produces a corresponding set of HTML
>   pages describing (**by default**) **the public and protected classes, nested
>   classes (but not anonymous inner classes)**, interfaces, constructors,
>   methods, and fields.

Comment: is ALL classes documented some-where online?

Comment: no, not ALL classes would be documented, but packaged for sure.